# next / last navigation not showing in Owl Carousel

Tags: carousel, owl-carousel

I am working on a website that uses owl carousel. Although the dots underneath the image carousel display correctly the last / next navigation does not.

I am probably missing something simple but thought it best to ask the experts!

The page is here:

https://wandering.yoga/retreats.html

"nav:true" is in the owl.carousel.min.js

I assumed tha was all that was needed to display the now / next chevrons

Nothing shows up.